# Decay chain diffferential equation

Tags: radiation, differential-equations

Consider I have a decay chain $A\rightarrow B \rightarrow C$. With decay constants $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$

If I would want to find an equation relating the number of nuclei B to the decay constants, would the correct method to be to sum up the different rates of changes due to each part?

Ie-

$$\frac{dN_{B}}{dt} = -\lambda_{B} N$$

Represents the number of B nuclei due to the decay of B nuclei into C nuclei. However since there is an additional production of  B  nuclei from A nuclei of rate of change:

$$N_{A}(t) =N_{0,a}e^{-\lambda_{a}t}$$
Hence the number of B production is

$$N_{0,q}-N_{A}= N_{0,a}(1-e^{-\lambda_{a}t})$$

Meaning the rate at which this changes the total B nuclei is

$$\frac{dN_{B}}{dt} = \lambda_{a}N_{0,a}e^{-\lambda_{a}t}$$

Would then correct logic follow that the sum of there contributions, is the total rate of change? Ie

$$\frac{dN_{B}}{dt} = -\lambda_{B} N_{B} + \lambda_{a}N_{0,a}e^{-\lambda_{a}t}$$

My only doubt is that apparently I should "multiply by $e^{\lambda_{B}t}$"  not sure what that means
[image]

Why would this 'hint' be given if I do not need it? Is there an approximate solution using this hint?

Comment: The original paper is H. Bateman, "The solution of a system of differential equations occurring in the theory of radioactive transformations", Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society Volume 15 423-427 (1910).

Comment: @JonCuster if this is the correct way to solve it, I am capable of solving. However  the environment at which this question was posed would.not require me to solve this differential equation, instead , apparent I should" times by e^lambdaBt and use integration by parts". I've edited my question with the text

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is basically it although I think you wrote it a bit inconsistent.

By that I mean: What is "N" without any index? I suppose you mean $N_B$ here aswell. Also, I think you lost the minus in $e^{-\lambda_at}$. And you could write $N_0 e^{-\lambda_at} = N_A(t)$. So that all in all it is:

$\frac{dN_B(t)}{dt} = -\lambda_B N_B(t)+\lambda_A N_A(t)$

Since the actual question was about "multiplying with $e^{\lambda_Bt}$". Here is how this solves the equation:

\begin{equation}
\dot{N}_B e^{\lambda_Bt} = -\lambda_B N_B(t) e^{\lambda_Bt}+\lambda_A N_A(t) e^{\lambda_Bt}
\end{equation}

Lets first integrate the left hand side of the euqtion, using integration by parts as suggested.

\begin{align}
LHS = \int_0^t \dot{N}_B e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} & = N_B(t^{'})e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}}|_0^t - \int_0^t N_B(t^{'}) \lambda_Be^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} \\
& = N_{B0} - N_B(t)e^{\lambda_Bt} - \int_0^t N_B(t^{'}) \lambda_Be^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'}
\end{align}
Compare the integral of the right side of the first equation:

\begin{align}
RHS = - \int_0^t N_B(t^{'}) \lambda_B e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} 
+ \int_0^t N_A(t^{'}) \lambda_A e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} 
\end{align}

We see that $- \int_0^t N_B(t^{'}) \lambda_B e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} $ appears in both expressions, therefore we have:
\begin{align}
N_B(t)e^{\lambda_Bt} = N_{B0} - \int_0^t N_A(t^{'}) \lambda_A e^{\lambda_Bt^{'}} dt^{'} 
\end{align}
Which is easily integrated, knowing that $N_A(t) = N_{A0}e^{-\lambda_A t}$

Comment: Also $N_0$ should probably have an index, since all species could have an initial amount of nuclei. So $N_{0A}$,$N_{0B}$ etc

Comment: Yeah I'll change it now, and thanks, I thought this was the correct way to solve